# Animate sorting of Collection View cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am trying to show the cells in a UICollectionView moving into place when the datasource array is sorted. I made the following attempt and for some reason the cells move to incorrect positions even though the sorting itself is done correctly. I know that because I can trigger a simple `reloadData()` afterwards and the cells will display in the correct order (without the moving animation of course). My logic is as follows, with `apples` being the datasource array:

```
let sortedApples = apples.sort({$0.tastiness < $1.tastiness})
let sortMap = apples.map({sortedApples.indexOf($0)!})

self.CollectionView.performBatchUpdates(
{
    for i in 0 ..< sortMap.count
    {
        if i != sortMap[i]
        {
             self.CollectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forItem: i, inSection: 0), toIndexPath: NSIndexPath.init(forItem: sortMap[i], inSection: 0))
        }
    }
},
completion:
{ finished in
    //apples = sortedApples
})
apples = sortedApples //tried this in the completion block too but that also didn't work
```

Can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong? Or if there's another working solution that would help too as long as it can work for variable cell heights.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just try with   self.CollectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forItem:sortMap[i], inSection: 0), toIndexPath: NSIndexPath.init(forItem: i, inSection: 0))

Comment: I think you should set `apples = sortedApples` before `CollectionView.performBatchUpdates`.

Comment: @a_tuo Yes you're right that was the problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: is optimization possible? What if I have 1000 of elements... that for loop will block my main UI thread.

Comment: @Fabiosoft that's an intersting question! Since you have to call moveItemAtIndexPath() for each moving cell and you obviously have to do it on the main thread, I believe you will need that for loop. One way to optimize it is to make another array or dictionary beforehand with only the mappings that involve visible cells and loop through that instead. However, this would probably not work if you have variable cell sizes, or if you have items being added or deleted at the same time, all of which my solution needed to account for. Did you find a more scalable solution?